# MySQL SELECT string operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM products 
WHERE (translation IS NULL OR translation = '') LIMIT 500
```

Now I would like to limit the results of the query to rows where name contains a string from this 2nd query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT matches FROM sorting
```

I know I can compare strings with something like name LIKE '%XXX%', but how can I compare with all the results of the 2nd query in one go?

Finally some of the matches are actually 2+ separate strings that needs to be compared separately. For example "big|large" means that the name should be compared with "big" and "large" separately.

Is that possible somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Either JOIN the tables, or have a condition with sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables and then use the IN clause. Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM products join sorting on sorting.someid = products.someid
WHERE (translation IS NULL OR translation = '') and matches in (SELECT DISTINCT matches FROM sorting)
LIMIT 500
```

**EDIT:-**

Also to add if you want to search a pattern then you can use REGEX but you need to find that pattern in your values. If you dont have any pattern then I dont think there is any way to match it.

Comment: @jarlh:- I was updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the "in" means that only exact matches are returned. I need a "like" functionality, so "this is a database" is matched with "database", etc.

Comment: @Louisa:- In that case you can use the Regex but for that you need to have a specific pattern else I am afraid that there is no such way to search that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` as `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name
FROM products JOIN sorting ON name LIKE '%' || matches || '%'
WHERE (translation IS NULL OR translation = '')
LIMIT 500
```

Maybe MySQL wants `concat('%',matches,'%'`) instead of ANSI SQL's `||` for concat.